# Login Page and storing data I have no clue and already tried

Tags: html

Can anybody help me make a login page and store username and password in a text file for practice.
  Thanks.

Comment: You can't achieve this using HTML alone.  You'll need JavaScript and a backend language too.

Comment: While you won't necessarily need Javascript for this, it is true that you will need some sort of backend code to get this working. I would recommend doing a web search for "how to create login page", or something along those lines, then go from there. There are plenty of tutorials out there which cover this topic. StackOverflow probably isn't the best place to ask such a broad question. However, if you can be more specific about what you've tried and where you're getting stuck, it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: ik how to make login page but just storing in a txt file

Comment: is their anyway you could email me @TomCatullo

Comment: so i can show you my code@TomCatullo

Comment: or maybe you could give a link bc. when i search nothing shows@TomCatullo

Comment: you would also need a server side language to write data to a txt file

Comment: like php? @GowthamShiva

Comment: exactly... php is one of those of server side languages. very easy to learn. by any chance you have a localhost server that has PHP?

Comment: yes I have Wamp @GowthamShiva

Comment: I would show you my html code but cant fit

Comment: @noah please add your html code to the question. and the php code too if you have

Comment: @GowthamShiva my

Comment: HTML code won't fit could you email me or something

Comment: @GowthamShiva I actually came on here bc I needed the php code to write the user input to w text file

Comment: @GowthamShiva can you add some style with CSS for me?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 php files as below,

**1: index.php**

```html
<html>
<form action="save.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" /><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

**2: save.php**

```html
<?php  
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$fp = fopen("log.txt", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "username: ".$username." password: ".$password);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Run this in your `WAMP` server and you will get the `username` and `password` saved in your `log.txt` file in the same location.

Comment: is there any chance you could add some style to it with css  ?

Comment: @noah I leave that part to you to google it find out. Please mark the answer as correct to close this question.